# I'm an admin (Windows 10 Home) and am told I don't have the authorization to uninstall an app I just installed. How do I uninstall it?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

I'm using an Administrator account. I can install an MSI for the current user only, but when I try to uninstall it, I get the error message

```
You do not have sufficient privileges to complete this installation for all users of the machine. Log on as administrator and then retry this installation.
```

The three ways I tried to uninstall the app:

1. From both a regular powershell and a run-as-admin powershell:

```
msiexec /x MyFile.msi
```

2. Just run `./MyFile.msi` and choose the `Remove` option
3. Run `appwiz.cpl` and choose to uninstall `MyFile`.

I suspect all three paths are to the same function that's failing. How can I delete this app?

If it's relevant, `MyFile.msi` was built with Wix.

Comment: Try passing ALLUSERS="" or ALLUSERS=2 in first alternative. Also, pass /l*v logfile.log for getting MSI log details.

Answer (score 0):

The Wix file from which the MSI was generated was flawed.

Fixed by using Orca to edit the MSI, and adding `AND NOT REMOVE` to the `SetALLUSERS` and `SetMSIINSTALLPERUSER` tasks for the `InstallExecuteSequence` and `InstallUISequence` things.

Thanks for offering an answer though, Vivek.

Comment: And this is why you always test your MSI thoroughly on a VM or in a sandbox session before ever installing it on your own machine.  It doesn't end well to take a proverbial dump in your own back yard.